# RNN and CNN-RNN won't train correctly, always predict one class

Tags: python, keras, nlp, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently developing a model to detect emotion from text using deep learning algorithms. I have a relatively small labelled dataset(~7500) with 7 different emotions as classes. I developed a CNN and achieved an accuracy of ~63% but when I tried to apply a RNN, using LSTM, and a CNN-RNN, also using LSTM, they just don't seem to train properly at all and always end up predicting the same class. I believe my models to be fundamentally sound but with some mistakes with the parameters. I have the dataset split up into 85% for training, with a further 20% of that for validation, and the remaining 15% for testing. My embedding matrix is developed using the word representations from the Google News word2vec and the word index is developed using keras Tokenizer.

Dataset breakdown:

Emotion

anger          1086

disgust        1074

fear           1086

guilt          1062

joy            1089

sadness        1080

shame          1058

CNN implementation

```
def make_model(kernel_sizes, num_filters, dropout, hidden_units):

    submodels = []
    for kernel_size in kernel_sizes:
        submodel = Sequential()

        submodel.add(Embedding(input_dim = input_dim,
                            output_dim   = output_dim,
                            weights      = [embedding_matrix],
                            input_length = max_len,
                            trainable    = True))

        submodel.add(Conv1D(filters=num_filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same',activation='relu',strides=1))
        submodel.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
        submodels.append(submodel)

    submodel_outputs = [model.output for model in submodels]    
    submodel_inputs = [model.input for model in submodels]

    merged = Concatenate(axis=1)(submodel_outputs)
    x = Dropout(dropout)(merged)

    if(hidden_units > 0):
        x = Dense(hidden_units, activation='relu')(x)
        x = Dropout(dropout)(x)

    x = Dense(7,activation='softmax', kernel_initializer="uniform")(x)
    out = Activation('sigmoid')(x)

    model = Model(submodel_inputs, out)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['acc'])

    return model
```

```
def fit_model(model, kernel_sizes, num_epochs, batch_size, x_train, y_train):

    x_train = [x_train]*len(kernel_sizes)

    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=num_epochs, validation_split=0.2)

    return history
```

```
kernel_sizes  = [2,6]
num_filters   = 100
dropout       = 0.6
num_hidden    = 270
callbacks     = callbacks_list
num_epochs    = 15
batch_size = 64
model = make_model(kernel_sizes, num_filters, dropout, num_hidden)
print(model.summary())
history = fit_model(model, kernel_sizes, num_epochs, batch_size, x_train, y_train)
```

Model: "model_1"

---

## Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to

embedding_1_input (InputLayer)  (None, 179)          0

---

embedding_2_input (InputLayer)  (None, 179)          0

---

embedding_1 (Embedding)         (None, 179, 300)     2729400     embedding_1_input[0][0]

---

embedding_2 (Embedding)         (None, 179, 300)     2729400     embedding_2_input[0][0]

---

conv1d_1 (Conv1D)               (None, 179, 100)     60100       embedding_1[0][0]

---

conv1d_2 (Conv1D)               (None, 179, 100)     180100      embedding_2[0][0]

---

global_max_pooling1d_1 (GlobalM (None, 100)          0           conv1d_1[0][0]

---

global_max_pooling1d_2 (GlobalM (None, 100)          0           conv1d_2[0][0]

---

concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 200)          0           global_max_pooling1d_1[0][0]
                                                                 global_max_pooling1d_2[0][0]

---

dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 200)          0           concatenate_1[0][0]

---

dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 270)          54270       dropout_1[0][0]

---

dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 270)          0           dense_1[0][0]

---

dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 7)            1897        dropout_2[0][0]

---

## activation_1 (Activation)       (None, 7)            0           dense_2[0][0]

Total params: 5,755,167
Trainable params: 5,755,167
Non-trainable params: 0

---

[Training and Validation results for CNN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1GeS.png)

[CNN confusion matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e88si.png)

---

RNN Implementation

```
def make_model(lstm_units, dropout, hidden_units):

    model = Sequential()   

    model.add(Embedding(input_dim = input_dim,
                        output_dim   = output_dim,
                        weights      = [embedding_matrix],
                        input_length = max_len,
                        trainable    = False))

    model.add(LSTM(lstm_units))

    model.add(Dropout(dropout))

    if(hidden_units > 0):
        model.add(Dense(hidden_units, activation='elu'))
        model.add(Dropout(dropout))

    model.add(Dense(7,activation='softmax', kernel_initializer="uniform"))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['acc'])

    return model
```

```
lstm_units = 120
dropout = 0.5
hidden_units = 550
callbacks = [tensorboard, early]
num_epochs = 20
batch_size = 60

model = make_model(lstm_units, dropout, hidden_units)
print(model.summary())
history = fit_model(model, num_epochs, batch_size, x_train, y_train)
```

Model: "sequential_6"

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

embedding_6 (Embedding)      (None, 179, 300)          2729400

---

lstm_8 (LSTM)                (None, 120)               202080

---

dropout_5 (Dropout)          (None, 120)               0

---

dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 550)               66550

---

dropout_6 (Dropout)          (None, 550)               0

---

dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 7)                 3857

---

## activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 7)                 0

Total params: 3,001,887
Trainable params: 272,487
Non-trainable params: 2,729,400

---

[RNN training and validation scores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7XIF.png)

[RNN confusion matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2CQe.png)

---

CNN-RNN implementation

```
def make_model(kernel_sizes, num_filters, dropout, hidden_units, lstm_units):

    submodels = []
    for kernel_size in kernel_sizes:
        submodel = Sequential()

        submodel.add(Embedding(input_dim = input_dim,
                            output_dim   = output_dim,
                            weights      = [embedding_matrix],
                            input_length = max_len,
                            trainable    = True))

        submodel.add(Conv1D(filters=num_filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same',activation='relu',strides=1))
        submodel.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides = 2))
        submodel.add(Dropout(dropout))
        submodel.add(LSTM(lstm_units)) 
        submodels.append(submodel)

    submodel_outputs = [model.output for model in submodels]    
    submodel_inputs = [model.input for model in submodels]

    merged = Concatenate(axis=1)(submodel_outputs)
    x = Dropout(dropout)(merged)

    if(hidden_units > 0):
        x = Dense(hidden_units, activation='relu')(x)
        x = Dropout(dropout)(x)

    x = Dense(7,activation='softmax', kernel_initializer="uniform")(x)
    out = Activation('sigmoid')(x)

    model = Model(submodel_inputs, out)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['acc'])

    return model
```

```
kernel_sizes  = [2,3,6]
num_filters   = 100
dropout       = 0.6
num_hidden    = 270
lstm_units = 80
callbacks     = [tensorboard, early]
num_epochs    = 20
batch_size = 64

model = make_model(kernel_sizes, num_filters, dropout, num_hidden, lstm_units)
print(model.summary())
history = fit_model(model, kernel_sizes, num_epochs, batch_size, x_train, y_train)
```

Model: "model_2"

---

## Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to

embedding_8_input (InputLayer)  (None, 179)          0

---

embedding_9_input (InputLayer)  (None, 179)          0

---

embedding_10_input (InputLayer) (None, 179)          0

---

embedding_8 (Embedding)         (None, 179, 300)     2729400     embedding_8_input[0][0]

---

embedding_9 (Embedding)         (None, 179, 300)     2729400     embedding_9_input[0][0]

---

embedding_10 (Embedding)        (None, 179, 300)     2729400     embedding_10_input[0][0]

---

conv1d_8 (Conv1D)               (None, 179, 100)     60100       embedding_8[0][0]

---

conv1d_9 (Conv1D)               (None, 179, 100)     90100       embedding_9[0][0]

---

conv1d_10 (Conv1D)              (None, 179, 100)     180100      embedding_10[0][0]

---

max_pooling1d_7 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 89, 100)      0           conv1d_8[0][0]

---

max_pooling1d_8 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 89, 100)      0           conv1d_9[0][0]

---

max_pooling1d_9 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 89, 100)      0           conv1d_10[0][0]

---

dropout_9 (Dropout)             (None, 89, 100)      0           max_pooling1d_7[0][0]

---

dropout_10 (Dropout)            (None, 89, 100)      0           max_pooling1d_8[0][0]

---

dropout_11 (Dropout)            (None, 89, 100)      0           max_pooling1d_9[0][0]

---

lstm_2 (LSTM)                   (None, 80)           57920       dropout_9[0][0]

---

lstm_3 (LSTM)                   (None, 80)           57920       dropout_10[0][0]

---

lstm_4 (LSTM)                   (None, 80)           57920       dropout_11[0][0]

---

concatenate_3 (Concatenate)     (None, 240)          0           lstm_2[0][0]
                                                                 lstm_3[0][0]
                                                                 lstm_4[0][0]

---

dropout_12 (Dropout)            (None, 240)          0           concatenate_3[0][0]

---

dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 270)          65070       dropout_12[0][0]

---

dropout_13 (Dropout)            (None, 270)          0           dense_3[0][0]

---

dense_4 (Dense)                 (None, 7)            1897        dropout_13[0][0]

---

## activation_2 (Activation)       (None, 7)            0           dense_4[0][0]

Total params: 8,759,227
Trainable params: 8,759,227
Non-trainable params: 0

---

[CNN-RNN training and validation scores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFTYk.png)
[CNN-RNN confusion matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUet2.png)

I understand there is no magic formula to neural networks and no one size fits all approach, I am just looking for some guidance in the areas which I may have made mistakes in when implementing the CNN-RNN and RNN.

Apologies in advance for any formatting errors as this is my first question asked. If there is any other info required please let me know.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your CNN implementation is over-enthusiastic, have you come up with the architecture by experimenting with multiple designs or just chose it?

Usually, when multiple heads are chosen they are fed a slightly variation of the input, not the exact same copy so maybe your multi-head design is not the most optimal choice, it introduces too many unnecessary parameters and can lead to overfitting and from your loss curve which is evident.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1GeS.png]

You used categorical crossentropy but used sigmoid after softmax, which is also not how things are done. Just use the softmax activation and get rid of the sigmoid.

Is the confusion matrix for test set? Then, it seems your test split is too easy, as the model is so much overfitted it should perform poorly. So, try to find a better test split by making sure not too much similar data falls in both training and testing.

It's always better to fine-tune your simpler model before going to complicated ones. As your LSTM model didn't perform well, it doesn't make sense to try a even more complicated model (CNN-LSTM). Your LSTM model didn't converge, the reasons can be many (the obvious ones being the incorrect usage of activation layer).

```
def make_model(lstm_units, dropout, hidden_units):

    model = Sequential()   

    model.add(Embedding(input_dim = input_dim,
                        output_dim   = output_dim,
                        weights      = [embedding_matrix],
                        input_length = max_len,
                        trainable    = False))

    model.add(LSTM(lstm_units, return_sequences = True, recurrent_dropout = 0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(LSTM(lstm_units, recurrent_dropout = 0.2))

    model.add(Dropout(dropout))


    model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['acc'])

    return model
```

Make it a fully LSTM based model by getting rid of the FC layers, also start with smaller LSTM units like ***8, 16, 32, ...***

For more improvement, you can do the following.

0) Get rid of the glove embedding and use your own learnable embedding.

1) Hyper-parameter search over the network to find the most optimal model.

There are many libraries, but I find this one very flexible. https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner

**Just install with pip.**

Here is a demo code.

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from kerastuner.tuners import RandomSearch


def build_model(hp):
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Embedding(input_dim=hp.Int('input_dim',
                                        min_value=5000,
                                        max_value=10000,
                                        step = 1000),
                              output_dim=hp.Int('output_dim',
                                        min_value=200,
                                        max_value=800,
                                        step = 100),
                              input_length = 400))
    model.add(layers.Convolution1D(
                filters=hp.Int('filters',
                                        min_value=32,
                                        max_value=512,
                                        step = 32),
                kernel_size=hp.Int('kernel_size',
                                        min_value=3,
                                        max_value=11,
                                        step = 2),
                padding='same',
                activation='relu')),
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D())
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(layers.Dense(units=hp.Int('units',
                                        min_value=64,
                                        max_value=256,
                                        step=32),
                           activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(
        hp.Choice('learning_rate',
                  values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])),
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


tuner = RandomSearch(
    build_model,
    objective='val_accuracy',
    max_trials=5,
    executions_per_trial=3,
    directory='my_dir',
    project_name='helloworld')
tuner.search_space_summary()

## The following lines are based on your model


tuner.search(x, y,
             epochs=5,
             validation_data=(val_x, val_y))

models = tuner.get_best_models(num_models=2)
```

If you want to extract more meaningful features, one approach I found promising is by extracting pre-trained BERT features and then training using a CNN/LSTM.

A great repository to get started is this one - 
https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers

Once you get the sentence embedding from the BERT/XLNet you can use those features to train another CNN similar to the one you are using except maybe get rid of the embedding layer as it's expensive.

Comment: I came up with the CNN by lots of trial and error, this was the model that performed best. When you say multi-head design are you referring to the use of the submodels? You are correct that the confusion matrix is from the test set. Thanks very much, some very useful feedback.

Comment: Yes, the submodels. Maybe the submodels are just making your model bulky and it's overfitting. For the scale of your dataset, a much simpler model should have been the choice.

Comment: Did you try the simpler LSTM model I provided with less units? If my answer helped you, kindly upvote/ accept :)

Comment: The simpler CNN was definitely an improvement on the previous implementation but the simpler LSTM is still struggling to train properly, never getting above 16% accuracy.

Comment: That's a good news, LSTMs are always harder to train, maybe there are not enough temporal features for LSTM to find. The simple CNN performing better also suggests, your task is too simple for applying inherent deep structures like LSTM.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to overcome this simplicity? My embedding matrix is currently developed using a word2vec containing 300 elements per vector.

Comment: I have updated my answer with more options and details, you may try those. If it helps, upvote me or accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't say this will solve all your issues, but something that is definitely wrong is your repeated use of the sigmoid activation right after a softmax activation, while your classification problem has 7 classes. The sigmoid activation can only separate two classes.

For instance:

```
model.add(Dense(7,activation='softmax', kernel_initializer="uniform"))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

You should just remove the sigmoid activation the three times you did this.